# How to split a string from one specific word in a string to another specific word in the same string in java?

Tags: java, json, string, android-studio, gson

So the string i'm working with is this API quiz thingy -> https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10

The problem is when the question contains the symbol " , " (it will then split up my string variables wrong)

My testcode:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String json = readUrl("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Quiz quiz = gson.fromJson(json, Quiz.class);

    String string = quiz.results.iterator().next().toString();
    String[] parts = string.split(",");

    // Category
    String part1 = parts[0];
    part1 = part1.replace("{category=", "");
    // Type
    String part2 = parts[1];
    part2 = part2.replace("type=", "");
    //Difficulty
    String part3 = parts[2];
    part3 = part3.replace("difficulty=", "");
    //Question
    String part4 = parts[3];
    part4 = part4.replace("question=", "");
    //Correct answers
    String part5 = parts[4];
    part5 = part5.replace("correct_answer=", "");
    //Incorrect answers
    String part6 = parts[5];
    part6 = part6.replace("incorrect_answers=[", "");
    //Output
    System.out.println("Category: " +        part1);
    System.out.println("Type: "    +         part2);
    System.out.println("Difficulty: " +      part3);
    System.out.println("Question: " +        part4);
    System.out.println("Correct answers: " + part5);
    System.out.println("Incorrect answers " +part6);
```

Any good ideas to solve this? Is there a good way to split the words in the string from the API-Url from one word to another? Example from the word "question=" to the word "correct_answers=" So i can save the string that is in the middle of thoose two words.

//readUrl method:

```
public static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        int read;
        char[] chars = new char[1024];
        while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
            buffer.append(chars, 0, read);

        return buffer.toString();
    } finally {
        if (reader != null)
            reader.close();
    }
}
```

//Quiz object class:

```
static class Quiz {
    private float response_code;
    ArrayList<Object> results = new ArrayList<Object>();


    // Getter Methods

    public float getResponse_code() {
        return response_code;
    }

    // Setter Methods

    public void setResponse_code(float response_code) {
        this.response_code = response_code;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the h* are you reading json like this?

Comment: thought it was a good idea to have the code as simple/small as possible for testing purposes. The question is not about how to read json, it's about how to split up a long string :) but yeah, i'm just a student and still learning, so every advice you may have about reading json ill take any day of the week.

Comment: try using JSONObject and JSONArray on parsing JSON rather than manipulating the string. I hope this can help https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm